# How to configure Nginx to serve https only

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I'm new in the web servers world, i wan't my site to serve https only (for both IPV4 & IPV6) so i implemented the following steps,

1. install letsencrypt.
2. install certbot with the Nginx plugin.
3. create the certificate using command,

sudo certbot --nginx certonly -d maarath.com -d www.maarath.com

4.manually configure my site configuration file in the etc/nginx/site-available/main like below ,

```
server {
        listen 80  ;
        listen [::]:80  ;
        root /var/www/main/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name maarath.com www.maarath.com;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

# HTTPS

    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name       maarath.com  www.maarath.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/maarath.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/maarath.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;




        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi.conf;
        }
        #deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        #concurs with nginx's one
        location ~ /\.ht {

        }
}
```

5. run command nginx -t with no issues.
6. restart nginx.

The issue is my site still not secure after all the above steps, did i miss something or did it wrong ? any help would be much appreciated .

Comment: may be you can redirect  the 80 port to 443

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fist off, I believe your config is missing the second `server {` right under `# HTTPS`

Just to get that right, your website `https://maarath.com` throws an SSL Error? Because from my perspective it works just fine. Or do you mean that `http` is not redirected to `https`?

If that's the case add

```
return 301 https://maarath.com$request_uri;
```

To your first server block. Right above

```
server_name ...
```

This should automatically redirect all requests from `http` to `https`.

Comment: Although this approach solves the problem, it makes your server prone to a vulnerability known Open Redirection.
For more information please read this:

https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/open-redirection-vulnerability-information-prevention/

The better solution is to solve this problem at the application layer.

Comment: @MajidJafari This is not true. The "Open Redirection Vulnerability" is about unverified user provided links (on an application layer based redirect service). This problem has nothing to do with the Webserver. It would be an issue if you'd try to handle it on an application layer as you suggested. That would be fatal as it could be exploited fairly easily.

Comment: could you please elaborate more on this? What's different here? How could web server layer redirection protect the Open Redirection?

Comment: @MajidJafari It does not "protect" anything. It just isn't _prone_ to the Open Redirection Vulnerability. The article mentions application layer based redirect services, for example `/index.php?redirect=...` and certainly not same-page webserver redirects (HTTP 3XX). Please read the article carefully before accusing my answer of being vulnerable / not secure.

Answer (score 6):

As NullDev mentioned, i just will add the new working configuration file hope to help someone else.

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80;
        server_name maarath.com www.maarath.com;

    # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
# HTTPS

    listen              443 ssl;

        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        root /var/www/main/ ;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name       maarath.com  www.maarath.com;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/maarath.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/maarath.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }




        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi.conf;
        }
        #deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        #concurs with nginx's one
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```